# Using Image Control with Stretch = UniformToFill - WP7

Tags: image, windows-phone-7.1, vertical-alignment, stretch, uniform

I have an image placed on a Page as follow

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Image Name="im" Source="/images/hqdefault.jpg" Height="250" Stretch="UniformToFill"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
```

this is the whole page XAML, image can be downloaded from http://i.ytimg.com/vi/wNKKCHv-oOw/hqdefault.jpg

Code behind contains some logic to handle the PageOrientation_Change

```
 private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    if (Orientation == PageOrientation.Landscape ||
        Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft ||
        Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight)
    {
       im.Height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
       im.Width = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;

       im.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
       im.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
     }
     else
     {
       im.Height = 250;
       im.Width = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
     }
  }
```

If some one may try this he/she may find that StrechToFill crops the content of the image from bottom where as I am expecting it to crop it from top and bottom equally and keep the image content centered within image control.

HOpe I have made myself clear if not please consider making a sample from provided code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Main problem was the setting of height or width on the Image control, i am now well aware not to give heigh or width on the image control nor on media element. if you need a a fixed height  for example in portrait mode you may put it in a grid control and set its height or width. following is the code which worked for me.

```
<Grid Name="grdMedia"
      Grid.Row="1" 
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      Height="250">
<Image Name="imThumbnail" 
       Grid.Row="1" 
       Stretch="UniformToFill" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

And following code if you want to change this picture to full screen in landscape mode

```
    private void SetUIInLandscape()
    {
        SystemTray.IsVisible = false;

       //Do not change the height or width of image control nor its alignments 
       //Hide every thing else

        grdMedia.Height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
        grdMedia.Width = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;

    }

    private void SetUIInPortrait()
    {
        SystemTray.IsVisible = true;

        //Do not change the height or width of image control nor its alignments
        //Make every thing else visible

        grdMedia.Height = 250;
        grdMedia.Width = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Image Name="im" Source="/images/hqdefault.jpg" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

try this then the u need not do anything in PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged event.

Comment: here is a thing when i set Stretch=UniformToFill it makes it bottom Aligned instead of center.

Comment: I think if u just remove it everything will be fine.. try removing it n putting just what i have mentioned.

Comment: The image would take the height of the row if the image is bigger than the row height.. else it would take its original height if u use Height.